# No complication configuration in xcode for watchOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, apple-watch, clockkit

I added a new watch app for an existing iOS App that is build with react native. I never developed a watch app before. I read everywhere that this should create two targets, the watch App and the App extension. But only a watch app gets created.

Now I want to add a complication for this watch app. I tried to follow the steps [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/creating_complications_for_your_watchos_app) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/creating_complications_for_your_watchos_app/enabling_complications_for_your_watchos_app). It says that on the general tab of the extension (which is not present in my project) I should configure *the Complication Configuration*. But this option is just not present.

[image: the options that are available]

Was this changed with watchOS 9 or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’m having a similar issue after creating a watchOS app in Xcode 13 without an initial complication. Fortunately, I was able to work around the missing configuration UI by manually setting the values.

Assuming you’ve followed [these steps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/creating_complications_for_your_watchos_app/enabling_complications_for_your_watchos_app)  of creating the `ComplicationController` class and “Complication” placeholder in Assets,

Go to Project -> watch app target -> Build Settings

1. Set “Complication Principal Class” to `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ComplicationController` under Info.plist Values
2. Set “Watch Complication Name” to `Complication` under Asset Catalog Compiler - Options

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to watch kit Complication and also start with the docs @jrenk provided, and then I found WidgetKit is replacing ClockKit in WWDC 2022. You should add a WidgetKit target in watchOS project.

ref:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/WidgetKit/Converting-A-ClockKit-App